# Are all the points in a nonempty open set limit points?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

My conjecture is that given any open set $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}$, all points $a\in A$ are limit points.

Prove, or if untrue, disprove by constructing a counterexample.

A few definitions for clarification:

- A set $A$ is **open** iff for every point $a\in A$, there exists a $\delta$ such that the neighborhood $\left(a-\delta,a+\delta\right)$ surrounding $a$ is completely contained within (is a subset of) $A$.
- A point $x$ is a **limit point** of a set $A$ iff given any $\varepsilon$, all neighborhoods $\left(x-\varepsilon,x+\varepsilon\right)$ intersect the set $A$ in some point other than $x$. Note that $x$ need not be a point in $A$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $a$ be a point in $A$. Since $A$ is open, there is a number $\delta > 0$ such that $(a - \delta, a + \delta) \subset A$.

We now show $a$ is a limit point of $A$. To that end, let $\epsilon > 0$ be given. We may assume, without loss of generality, that $\epsilon < \delta$. Now, $(a - \epsilon, a + \epsilon) \subset (a - \delta, a + \delta) \subset A$, so $(a - \epsilon, a + \epsilon) \cap A = (a - \epsilon, a + \epsilon)$. Since $(a - \epsilon, a + \epsilon)$ intersects $A$ in a point other than $a$, we conclude $a$ is a limit point.

Comment: But what happens if $\delta < \epsilon$?

Comment: @chharvey If $\delta < \epsilon$, then $(a - \delta, a + \delta) \subset (a - \epsilon, a + \epsilon)$, so $(a - \delta, a + \delta) \subset (a - \epsilon, a + \epsilon) \cap A)$. Openness already gives you an open $\delta$-interval around $a$, so you only need to worry about the case where $\epsilon$ is smaller than that.

Comment: Still a bit confused but see if I can interpret correctly. First, $D \subseteq E$ does not by itself imply that $D \subseteq (E \cap A)$, I think you would also need to mention $D \subseteq A$. Second, I think What you're saying is that if $(a-\delta,a+\delta) \subseteq (a-\epsilon,a+\epsilon)\cup A$, then $\{a\} \subset (a-\epsilon,a+\epsilon)\cup A$ (strictly), which is what we need for a limit  point. Is that right? If so, the cases $\epsilon < \delta$ and $\delta < \epsilon$ are different, so I would suggest rigorously including the second case in your proof (and drop the "WLOG").

Comment: @chharvey You are right that $D \subset A$ is also needed, but that is given to us by openness. Indeed, that's how $\delta$ was chosen. I disagree that the cases need to be treated separately, but that is a matter of aesthetics more than rigor. In my mind, we already have a $\delta$-interval centered around $a$ and completely contained in $A$, so we only need to worry whether *smaller* intervals intersect $A$ in a point other than $a$.

Answer (score 0):

To say that all points $a\in A$ are limit points is to say that there is no point $b\in A$ that is an **isolated point**.

To prove this, we will use a method called *proof by contradiction*, in which we assume the negation and see if we can arrive at a nonsensical conclusion. If we can arrive at a contradiction, then our assumption—namely, the negation of the conjecture—must be false. This will prove that the conjecture itself is true.

Let's assume to the contrary that an open set $A$ does indeed contain an isolated point $b$.

If $A$ is open, then *every point in $A$, including $b$*, must have some neighborhood that is a subset of $A$. This means that there must exist some $\delta$ such that every point within the neighborhood $\left(b-\delta,b+\delta\right)$ must be a member of the set $A$. Since the interval is open, let there be a point $d\in\left(b-\delta,b+\delta\right)$ such that $d\ne b$. Then $d\in A$.

Now, if $b$ is an isolated point, then it is *not* a limit point by definition. Thus we must negate the definition of **limit point**. If $b$ is an isolated point, there must exist some $\varepsilon$ such that the neighborhood $\left(b-\varepsilon,b+\varepsilon\right)$ intersects the set $A$ *only* at the point $b$. Since the interval is open, let there be a point $e\in\left(b-\varepsilon,b+\varepsilon\right)$ such that $e\ne b$. Then $e\not\in A$.

For simplicity, assign the following symbols:

$$V_\delta(b) = \left(b-\delta,b+\delta\right)$$
$$V_\varepsilon(b) = \left(b-\varepsilon,b+\varepsilon\right)$$

There are two possibilities:

1. $$V_\delta(b) \subseteq V_\varepsilon(b)$$

   Then for all $d \ne b$, we have $d\in V_\delta(b) \implies d\in V_\varepsilon(b)$. From the conclusions above, this implies $d\in A \implies d\not\in A$. This is a contradiction.
2. $$V_\delta(b) \supseteq V_\varepsilon(b)$$

   This is the converse of Case 1. We still arrive at a contradiction.

Since both cases lead to a contradiction, our assumption that $A$ is open and contains an isolated point $b$ is faulty. Thus there can be no such possibility. In conclusion, any open set $A$ must not contain any isolated points. In other words, all the points in a (nonempty) open set are limit points. *q.e.d.*

---

A few notes:

1. Just because a nonempty open set contains only limit points does not mean that the set contains *all* its limit points. For example, all points in the open interval $(0,1)$ are limit points, but this set does not contain the limit points $0$ and $1$.
2. The converse of your conjecture states, "If every point in a set is a limit point, then that set is open." This is false. The closed interval $[0,1]$ provides a counterexample: every point within this interval is a limit point, but it is not an open set.

Comment: I think contradiction complicates this proof unnecessarily.

Answer (score 0):

## Alternative answer

Rather than using the neighborhood definitions shown in the question, see the sequential definitions below:

- A set $A$ is **open** iff for every sequence $\left(x_n\right)\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ that converges to a point $a\in A$, $\left(x_n\right)$ is *eventually* in $A$. Here *eventually*  means there exists an $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that when $n\gt N$, $x_n \in A$.
- A point $x$ is a **limit point** of a set $A$ iff there exists a sequence $\left(a_n\right)\subseteq A$, satisfying $a_n\not=x$, that converges to $x$. Note that $x$ need not be a point in $A$.
- A sequence $(b_n)$ **converges** to a point $b$ iff for any $\delta \gt 0$, there exists an $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that if $n\gt N$ then $|b_n - b| < \delta$. Put another way, $b_n\in\left(b-\delta,b+\delta\right)$.

Assume $A$ is open and contains a point $a$. Because $A$ is open, every sequence $(x_n)\to a$ will eventually be contained in $A$. In other words, there exists some point in the sequence $x_N$ after which all the terms $x_n$ will be in $A$.

For any sequence $(x_n)\to a$ under the condition that $x_n\not=a$, define the sequence $(a_n)$ by

$$a_n = x_{(N+1+n)}$$

To see this clearly, notice $a_0 = x_{(N+1)}$, $a_1 = x_{(N+2)}$, etc. Essentially the sequence $(a_n)$ is the "tail end" of the sequence $(x_n)$, where the first term $a_0$ is the point at which $(x_n)$ enters the set $A$, never to leave. It is easy to see that $(a_n)\subseteq A$, $(a_n)\to a$, and $a_n\not=a$ for any $n$. Thus $a\in A$ is a limit point of $A$.

*q.e.d.*